# R How to print non zero frequency table values in rows

Tags: r, frequency

Table prints rows and columns and the number of occurrences at the intersections.  I have a large table that is almost all zeros.  Can table be printed in rows instead, with the first column being the name of the table row, the second column being the name of the table column, and the third column being the number of occurrences.

```
library(data.table)
nSamples=10
set.seed(13)
d <- data.table(id=sample(1001:1010,nSamples,replace=T),
                own=sample(paste('h-',7:10,sep=''),nSamples,replace=T))
tbl<-table(d)
print(tbl)
```

The output looks like

```
      own
id     h-10 h-8 h-9
  1001    0   1   2
  1003    1   0   0
  1004    1   0   0
  1006    0   1   0
  1008    0   0   2
  1009    1   0   0
  1010    0   0   1
```

The output I would like is

```
     id  own Freq
   1003 h-10    1
   1004 h-10    1
   1009 h-10    1
   and so on
```

Note: the question was modified by correcting the set.seed.

The answer provided below gives the desired result

```
R> subset(as.data.frame(table(d)),Freq>0)
     id  own Freq
2  1003 h-10    1
3  1004 h-10    1
6  1009 h-10    1
8  1001  h-8    1
11 1006  h-8    1
15 1001  h-9    2
19 1008  h-9    2
21 1010  h-9    1
```

Comment: `as.data.frame(table(d))` would get the required format

Comment: Use `set.seed(123)` to set the seed

Comment: If you want to subset the result to only values > 0, you can do, with data.table: `as.data.table(table(d))[N > 0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) To convert to `long` format**

```
as.data.frame(table(d))
```

or if you need a `data.table`

```
as.data.table(table(d))
```

**2) set.seed issue**

You are assigning `<-` `set.seed` to 1. The correct way would be:

```
set.seed(1)
```

**3) For subsetting Freq >0**

```
setkey(as.data.table(table(d)),N)[N>0]
```

If there are only `0s` and `1s`

```
setkey(as.data.table(table(d)),N)[J(1)]
```

or the `data.frame` approach

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(d)),Freq>0)
```

#### EDIT

You can avoid using the `table` and then converting back to `long` form (as commented by @Arun).  Instead

```
 d[, .N, by=names(d)]
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks, Yes, it is.  I was just following the OP's code.